tailwind style is not working in next app when i added tailwind-merge dependency
im getting this Tailwind issue
i'm following tutorials from Youtube.. its a Spotify clone using next, tailwind..
GitHub Project link here
im trying to design this side bar, after i have added tailwind-merge dependency,, styles are not getting applied to my project,,
and doesn't work even if i remove remove this dependency,

Expected sidebar

Vs

Reality Sidebar (Clearly a tailwind issue)

Vs

When i create a new Next project and copy the same App, component folder and some dependencies

tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;

package.json
{
  "name": "spotify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


Install tailwind-merge, it won't have any impact on your styles unless you use it in your code. If you think that tailwind-merge is causing an issue, try uninstalling it to see if that solves the problem. If everything goes back to normal after uninstalling it, then the problem might be with tailwind-merge. If not, then there might be something else going on with your code.

i tried to uninstall tailwind-merge, but still the same issue,
actually i came to know that, its happening when i start with the fresh project,
the tailwind css will work initial couple of renders,, till i stop the server and re run the 'npm run dev' command
after the couple of 'npm run dev' i encounter with the styling issue

It seems you may have misconfigured your content file globs:
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],

You have the sidebar code in component folder (no s suffix). This folder is not covered by your content file globs. Consider adding/amending your globs:
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    // No 's', `components` → `component`
    "./component/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],


I ran into a similar issue and here is how I solved it...
When destructuring the props for the component, I forgot to also destructure className which I defined in my interface. Here is my wrong code snippet:
// imports

interface BoxProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

// Did not destructure `className` so it was undefined
export default function Box({ children }: BoxProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(`h-fit w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-900`, className)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

And here is the correct snippet
// Code above remains the same

// Now I am also destructuring `className` and it works
export default function Box({ children, className }: BoxProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(`h-fit w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-900`, className)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

